# Why can't any sample run in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code, abp

I can't run [any sample](https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples) of ABP on VS code
Please correct me.
Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI1nE.png)

Comment: Please include the error message as text, not an image.

Comment: The error is that your code can't connect to SQL Server. Do you have a SQL Server instance set up and running? Check that the connection string in the code is correct to connect to it. I don't know ABP but the connection string will probably be set in app.config or web.config.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update db connection string located at `appsettings.json` in DbMigrator project.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "Default": "Server=localhost;Database=DashboardDemo;Trusted_Connection=True"
}
```

It seems you don't have sql instance. Assuming you have localdb; changing `localhost` to `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` should work.

I suggest you to check [getting started guide](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-Running-Solution?UI=MVC&DB=EF&Tiered=No).